# Custom PyTorch optimizer is not working properly and am unable to access gradients

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to implement the elastic averaging stochastic gradient descent (EASGD) algorithm from the paper [*Deep Learning with Elastic Averaging SGD*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6651) and was running into some trouble.

I'm using PyTorch's [`torch.optim.Optimizer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#torch.optim.Optimizer) class and referencing the [official implementation of SGD](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD) and the [official implementation of Accelerated SGD](https://github.com/rahulkidambi/AccSGD/blob/master/AccSGD.py) in order to start off somewhere.

The code that I have is:

```
import torch.optim as optim


class EASGD(optim.Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, params, lr, tau, alpha=0.001):
        self.alpha = alpha

        if lr < 0.0:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid learning rate {lr}.")

        defaults = dict(lr=lr, alpha=alpha, tau=tau)
        super(EASGD, self).__init__(params, defaults)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        super(EASGD, self).__setstate__(state)

    def step(self, closure=None):
        loss = None
        if closure is not None:
            with torch.enable_grad():
                loss = closure()

        for group in self.param_groups:
            tau = group['tau']

            for t, p in enumerate(group['params']):
                x_normal = p.clone()
                x_tilde = p.clone()

                if p.grad is None:
                    continue

                if t % tau == 0:
                    p = p - self.alpha * (x_normal - x_tilde)
                    x_tilde = x_tilde + self.alpha * (x_normal - x_tilde)

                d_p = p.grad.data
                p.data.add_(d_p, alpha=-group['lr'])

        return loss
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> /home/user/github/test-repo/easgd.py:50: UserWarning: The `.grad` attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during `autograd.backward()`. If you indeed want the gradient for a non-leaf Tensor, use `.retain_grad()` on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations.

Reading [this PyTorch Discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/leaf-variable-was-used-in-an-inplace-operation/308) helped understand what the difference between leaf and non-leaf variables are, but I'm not sure how I should fix my code to make it work properly.

Any tips on what to do or where to look are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the ```p``` in ```for t, p in enumerate(group['params']):``` is a leaf tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you are copying `p` on this line:

```
p = p - self.alpha * (x_normal - x_tilde)
```

If this line gets execute (which the case in the first cycle when `t=0`) the following line raises the error because `p` doesn't have `.grad` attribute anymore.

You should use inplace operators instead, `add_`, `mult_`, `sub_`, `divide_`, etc...

```
for t, p in enumerate(group['params']):
    if p.grad is None:
        continue
    d_p = p.grad.data

    if t % tau == 0:
        d_p.sub_(self.alpha*0.01)

    p.data.add_(d_p, alpha=-group['lr'])
```

Above, I have removed `x_normal`, `x_tilde` since you didn't give them proper values. But I hope you get the idea. Only use inplace operator when working with the data inside the `step` function.